# How to convert great_circle distance to timedelta in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta, great-circle

I have used great_circle function to find the distance between two coordinates.For example, if i have the following data:

```
lat1= ['-77.85']
lon1= ['80.23']
lat2= [-22.4532']
lon2= ['62.45']
```

And to find the distance i use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.distance import great_circle
from datetime import datetime,timedelta as dt
distance = df.apply(lambda x: great_circle((x['lat1'], x['lon1']),(x['lat2'], x['lon2'])), axis = 1)  # gives distance in km
```

And to find the time from the distance, as we know Time = Distance/Speed.
I assume speed to be 80km/hr and I use:

```
time= distance/80
```

The obtained 'time' has the unit 'km' . I want to convert this function to time.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(time,unit='h')
```

I obtain the following error:

```
Error : ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: class 'geopy.distance.great_circle'
```

Could you tell me how to obtain 'time' as time function and not as distance 'km'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `.km` attribute.

Demo:

```
In [33]: df
Out[33]:
    lat1   lon1     lat2   lon2
0 -77.85  80.23 -22.4532  62.45

In [34]: distance = x.apply(lambda x: great_circle((x['lat1'], x['lon1']),
                                                   (x['lat2'], x['lon2'])).km,
                                                   axis = 1)
#  ---->                                                                  ^^^

In [35]: distance
Out[35]:
0    6233.235674
dtype: float64

In [36]: df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(distance/80,unit='h')

In [37]: df
Out[37]:
    lat1   lon1     lat2   lon2                   time
0 -77.85  80.23 -22.4532  62.45 3 days 05:54:55.605600
```

Comment: I tried it. I get the same error. ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'geopy.distance.great_circle'>

Comment: are you sure you have specified `.km` attribute? It should have returned `float64` dtype

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure time is correctly formated and never input floats.

You can convert a float to minutes and hours with the following command:

```
# time = distance / speed
time = 2.75 # 2 hours + 45 minutes
result = '0 days {0:02.0f}:{1:02.0f}:00'.format(*divmod(time * 60, 60)).split(":")

 # => result = "0 days 02:45:00"

df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(result)   #now it should work
```

Comment: yeah!! but the distance has the unit 'km' by default ! so i am not able to convert it into time function

Comment: You said it: time = distance/speed